# Python Syntax Error for Iterative Addition e.g. x += 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Building a stock data scraper for Finviz. I am using Spyder3 installed via Anaconda for Python 3.7.

My code is below. When I execute the x = 0, and then x = x+1 code line by line in the terminal, it works just fine. When I run entire script, I getthe same error if I use x += 1 or x = x + 1.

```
def finviz_query(tickerlist):

'''Get's source code from FinViz and Creates a List of Lists for Export '''
url="https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=140&t=" + str(stocks)
response = requests.get(url)
source=response.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source)
priceLST = [i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all('a')]
del priceLST[0:37]
del priceLST[len(priceLST)-2:len(priceLST)]
stockLST = re.split(',',stocks)
stock_outputLST = []
while len(priceLST) > 0:
    if priceLST[0] in stockLST:
        stock_outputLST.append([priceLST[0:16]])
        del priceLST[0:16]
    if len(priceLST) < 1:
        break
x = 0
while x < len(stock_outputLST):
    if x < len(stock_outputLST):
        stock_outputLST[x][0].append(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d;%H:%M")
        x = x + 1
    else:
        break
stock_outputLST[len(stock_outputLST)-1][0].append('0')
stock_outputLST[len(stock_outputLST)-1][0].append(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d;%H:%M"))
```

The error output is here:

```
...:stock_outputLST[len(stock_outputLST)-1][0].append(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d;%H:%M"))
...: return print('finviz_query complete')
  File "<ipython-input-114-81b306b1a6de>", line 22
    x = x + 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As usual, you're missing a close-paren on the previous line.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Greg also responded with the same. You guys can see these things so quickly it is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you get an error like this that doesn't quite make sense, look at the line above:

```
    stock_outputLST[x][0].append(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d;%H:%M")
```

You're missing a closing parenthesis `)` at the end.

Comment: Doh! Thank you much appreciated. I feel so stupid.

Comment: @bio_inf_dreamer: Everybody makes this mistake because it's so easy to do, just that when you get more experience after having done it dozens of times, you learn what to look for. :)